# Issue when retrieved date value is greater than 2030 from SQL to vb.net datetimepciker

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetimepicker

Retrieving Date value from `sql` into `datetimepicker` in Vb.Net form using `sql` data table. For dates with year 2030 or more, value is displayed as 1930 in `datetime` picker. Please help in solving this issue.

Code to retrieve value:

> dtpDate.Value = sqlDT.Rows(i)("StartDate").ToString

For example,

> If retrieved value of sqlDT.Rows(i)("StartDate").ToString is'10/30/2032' 
>   then dtpDate value is displayed as '10/30/1932'.

This code is working fine for all the dates till `2030 year`.

Comment: `DataTimePicker.Value` is of type `Date` - you can try pass instance of correct type `dtpDate.Value = sqlDT.Rows(i).Field(Of Date)("StartDate");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataTimePicker.Value` is of type `Date`.

You should give value of correct type

```
dtpDate.Value = sqlDT.Rows(i).Field(Of Date)("StartDate")
```

When working with vb.net you should set "Option Strict" setting to `On` in project settings or locally for the file writing `Option Strict On` on the first line of file.

In your case with `Option Strict On` you get compile error "String can not be converted to Date", which possible saves your time.